# get the values and pass it into the variable in to for loop on shell

Tags: shell

I want to write script to get the values given lists without prefix,suffix extensions. this part was working successfully.

```
`#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do

    basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf

done`
```

And then it should be passed variable in to for loop.after that that variable should run below command,

`/usr/bin/perl -config=$variable -update`

above command need to try concurrently using variable.can anyone know solve to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working successfully in below code.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    /usr/bin/perl -config="$(basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf)" -update 
done
```